# How to set the log4J configuration file in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, log4j

I'm trying to use log4j in JSP web application over Jboss 4.2
My problem is that I can't set the logger to use the properties file.
Here are the steps I done:

1. copy log4j.properties to WEB-INF folder
2. My code:
   <%@ page import="org.apache.log4j.Logger" %>
   <%@ page import="org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator" %>

<%
org.apache.log4j.Logger log = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("ApplicationA");
log.debug("Debug message");
%>

1. I tried to add to web.xml:

   log4jConfigLocation
   /WEB-INF/log4j.properties

The logger is worked but seems that with some default properties, e.g. only info messages are shown and it don't use the appenders in the config file

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 2):

`log4j.properties` needs to go in `/WEB-INF/classes`, not `/WEB-INF`